# php password_hash and password_verify fail

Tags: php

Basic question but I keep failing. Have checked out similar topics but didn't get closer to the solution, so please don't redirect me just point out what I'm missing. Thank you.

```
<?php 

$hashed_password = "";
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testTable");

if (isset($_POST["reg_button"])){

$password = ($_POST["reg_password"]);

$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user VALUES('', '$hashed_password')");

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <input type="password" name="reg_password" placeholder="Password">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="reg_button" value="Register">
    </form>
    <br>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <input type="password" name="login_password" placeholder="Password">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the registering part and it is working flawlessly. The provided password is getting hased and stored in the DB.

```
<?php

include "register.php";

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testTable");

if(isset($_POST["login_button"])){

    $password = password_verify($_POST["login_password"], $hashed_password);

    $checkDB = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE password = '$password'");

    $checkLogin = mysqli_num_rows($checkDB);

    if($checkLogin == 1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($checkDB);

        echo "Welcome";
    }

    else {
        echo "Password incorrect";
    }
}
?>
```

This is the login part and it always fails. I suspect the following snippet to be the culprit:

```
$password = password_verify($_POST["login_password"], $hashed_password);
```

but have no idea how to fix it.

Any help would be great. Thank you!

UPDATED CODE:

register.php:

```
<?php 

$hashed_password = "";
$name = "";
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testTable");

if (isset($_POST["reg_button"])){

    $password = ($_POST["reg_password"]);
    $name = ($_POST["reg_name"]);

    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user VALUES('', '$name','$hashed_password')");

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="reg_name" placeholder="Name">
        <br><br>
        <input type="password" name="reg_password" placeholder="Password">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="reg_button" value="Register">
    </form>
    <br>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="login_name" placeholder="Name">
        <br><br>
        <input type="password" name="login_password" placeholder="Password">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php:

```
<?php

include "register.php";

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testTable");

if(isset($_POST["login_button"])){

    $name = $_POST['login_name'];
    $password = $_POST['login_password'];

    $checkDB = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = '$name'");

    $passwordField = null;

    while($getRow = mysqli_num_rows($checkDB)){
        $passwordField = $getRow['password']; // Get hashed password
    }

    if(password_verify($password, $passwordField)){
        echo('Correct');
    }else{
        echo('Wrong');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via while loop and mysqli_fetch_array(). That must solve your problem.: [UPDATED]

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testtable");

if(isset($_POST["login_button"])){

    // $password = password_verify($_POST["login_password"], $hashed_password);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $checkDB = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user");

    while($getRow = mysqli_fetch_array($checkDB)){
        $passwordRow = $getRow['password'];
    }

    if(password_verify($password, $passwordRow) === TRUE){
        echo('Welcome');
    }else{
    echo('Wrong credentials');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Tried to use your code, registering works fine but when it comes to login this is what I face with: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\login.php on line 16. Apparently 'while' makes it crash

Comment: Is there only one field (password) in your form?

Comment: No, I added a 'name' field as well, please see updated code above

Comment: Please see updated answer. It's with only one field password.

Comment: Thanks for the update and your time, John. Now it is working as expected.

Comment: I am sorry @idontgetit. In your updated code in while loop instead of mysqli_num_rows() please replace it with mysqli_fetch_array().

Comment: That's awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Below from where do you get $hashed_password?Even if you included register.php,it doenst do anything,since those values are not set.

```
$password = password_verify($_POST["login_password"], $hashed_password);
```

You first need to get it from the db.

Second, `password_verify` returns true or false so even if $hashed_password is set,$password would be a boolean.

Comment: I thought $hashed_password gets its value if I include "register.php", as I did. Is it not? How should I assign a value to it then?

Comment: @idontgetit You cant login and register at the same time.Get the hash from the db:`SELECT pass_column FROM...WHERE username=..`